# How to deserialize java objects from kafka with Spark StructuredStream API, with no Avro or Json?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have created a topic in kafka called "test" which has just one partition and it is not replicated.

I have created a Kafka producer that writes on the topic "test" a key, that is the index of each cycle's iteration, and a value, that is an object of type Word in a cycle of 100000 iterations. Each word's property "word" is set to the iteration index and each word's property "timestamp" is set to the current timestamp. There is a 1000 ms of sleep between the iterations (Thread.sleep). Here is the definition of Word:

```
public class Word implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String word;

    private Long timestamp;

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Word [word=" + word + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((timestamp == null) ? 0 : timestamp.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((word == null) ? 0 : word.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Word other = (Word) obj;
        if (timestamp == null) {
            if (other.timestamp != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!timestamp.equals(other.timestamp))
            return false;
        if (word == null) {
            if (other.word != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!word.equals(other.word))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

The following is the class that uses StructuredStreaming API. As you can see, I register a deserializer class with the name "deserialize", then I use the class to transform a column of the dataframe df that is built from kafka. I will spare you the details of the Deserializer class, because, as you see in the stack trace, the class is correctely deserialized. The point is that, after deserialization, the cast to the Word schema fails.

```
public class StreamObjsFromKafka {

    public static void es() throws StreamingQueryException {
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("streamFromKafka").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = session.readStream().format("kafka")
                .option("group.id","test-consumer-group")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "test").load();

        df.printSchema();

        StructField word = DataTypes.createStructField("word", DataTypes.StringType, true);
        StructField timestamp = DataTypes.createStructField("timestamp", DataTypes.LongType, true);
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(word, timestamp));

        session.udf().register("deserialize", new WordDeserializer(), schema);

        Dataset<Row> df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) as KEY", "deserialize(value) AS value");

        StreamingQuery query0 = df1.writeStream().outputMode("update").format("console").start();

        query0.awaitTermination();

    }

}
```

The following lines are the first ones of the stacktrace (I'll spare you useless details):

```
18/12/06 15:21:03 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$259: (binary) => struct<word:string,timestamp:bigint>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (Word [word=15, timestamp=1544106059933]) of the type (kafka.model.Word) cannot be converted to struct<word:string,timestamp:bigint>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:396)
    ... 17 more
18/12/06 15:21:03 ERROR DataWritingSparkTask: Aborting commit for partition 0 (task 0, attempt 0stage 0.0)
18/12/06 15:21:03 ERROR DataWritingSparkTask: Aborted commit for partition 0 (task 0, attempt 0stage 0.0)
18/12/06 15:21:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$259: (binary) => struct<word:string,timestamp:bigint>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (Word [word=15, timestamp=1544106059933]) of the type (kafka.model.Word) cannot be converted to struct<word:string,timestamp:bigint>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:396)
    ... 17 more
18/12/06 15:21:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$259: (binary) => struct<word:string,timestamp:bigint>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$anonfun$run$3.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec$$anonfun$doExecute$2.apply(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (Word [word=15, timestamp=1544106059933]) of the type (kafka.model.Word) cannot be converted to struct<word:string,timestamp:bigint>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:396)
    ... 17 more
```

I think that the most important line of the stacktrace is the following:

```
The value (Word [word=15, timestamp=1544106059933]) of the type (kafka.model.Word) cannot be converted to struct<word:string,timestamp:bigint>
```

As you can see in the above line, the deserialization works properly: "(Word [word=15, timestamp=1544106059933])" is exactly what Kafka Producer has written to "test" topic. However, it doesn't cast it property to the following StructType schema: "struct". I can't understand why.

Comment: Why use Java serializer instead of something more common like Avro or even just JSON?

Comment: @cricket_007, yeas, maybe I could use JSON or Avro, but I think it should work as in this example as well and I'd like to understand why it does not work anyway. Do you think it is useless? Maybe I should rephrase the question. The point is not how to deserialize objects, but how to do that withoud Avro or json approach.

Comment: I've never implemented a deserializer for a raw Java object without using those formats. That's all. Typically Kyro in Spark does that, I think

Comment: Can you please post the code for WordDeserializer?